# PHP Simplest Method of Tokenizing A Comma Delmited List With Integrity

Tags: php, string, tokenize

I have been having a debate with a developer about the code that follows. What it is a function that will take either a scalar integer or a one-dimensional array of scalar integers as $comment_id. The goal is to transform something like `$comment_id = 16;` or `$comment_id = '16';` or `$comment_id = array(1, '2', 3, '4', 5, ...)` to `$id_string = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5';` The $id_string will be used in an SQL WHERE NOT IN clause to exclude certain primary keys from the results. This function will be widely used in our application so it's important it runs fast but also with integrity for security reasons.

Given the above example I ask 1. Will this function do what I set out to accomplish and 2. If not, then can you offer an alternative. Thank you for your time.

Code:

```
public function int_or_array_to_comma_list($comment_id)
{
    if( ! is_array($comment_id))
    {
        if( ! is_numeric($comment_id)) throw new Exception();

        $comment_id = intval($comment_id);

        // is $comment_id a integer?
        if($comment_id === 0) throw new Exception();

        $values = array($comment_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $values = $comment_id;
    }

    if(empty($values)) throw new Exception();

    $id_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($values); $i++)
    {
        // does the passed array keys follow the 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... pattern?
        if( ! isset($values[$i]) OR ! is_numeric($values[$i])) throw new Exception;

        $values[$i] = intval($values[$i]);

        // is $comment_id a integer?
        if(0 === $values[$i]) throw new Exception();

        // build comma list, if final array value exlude comma
        $id_string .= ($i !== count($values))? $values[$i] . ', ' : $values[$i];
    }

    return $comment_id;
}
```

Comment: but you never debated code indentation?

Comment: It was indented nicely, I pasted it here then manually put four spaces at each line. This ruined the formatting. I tried to add more space to correct the indenting but I got a system message saying it doesn't look like code.

Comment: @MichaelRich . . . This has nothing to do with MySQL so I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code above could be rewritten like this:

```
$values = array_map('intval', (array)$comment_id);

if(count(array_filter($values)) <> count($values))
  throw new \Exception();

$id_string = implode(',', $values);
```

`intval()` will cast non-numeric strings to 0, and `array_filter()` will remove any `0` values, so the exception will be raised in case invalid IDs are passed.

I guess you can do more validation if you need to, like drop duplicates with `array_unique()`, check for positive numbers etc.

Also, you might want to prepare your statement, that way you only need to make sure that the placeholder count matches the number of ids:

```
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($values)), ',');
$whereSql = sprintf('WHERE NOT IN(%s)', $placeholders);
```

Comment: This is quite a remarkable use of the php functions. Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
function int_or_array_to_comma_list($comment_id)
{
    return implode(',', array_map('intval', explode(',', implode(',', (array)$comment_id))));
}
```

Any database will ignore duplicate values in an `IN` clause, and invalid IDs don't matter as long as the search column is indexed like IDs usually are, so this is the one size fits all solution.

The `intval` call will ensure invalid results also return `0`, so for wholly invalid inputs this means the resulting query will be similar to `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (0)` which is fine to execute. Even edge cases with comma separated inputs nested in the array will be handled fine.

[Working sample visible here](https://eval.in/78226).